# Has Tony Stark ever tried synthesizing Vibranium?

Tags: marvel, iron-man, vibranium

In *[Iron Man 2](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt1228705/)*, Tony is shown successfully synthesizing a new element, and quite effortlessly actually.

If Tony is able to do this, wouldn't he also be able to make Vibranium?

#### Has Tony Stark ever attempted to synthesize Vibranium, possibly enough make an Iron Man suit out of it? Or, at least considered the thought?

If not, is there a specific characteristic to Vibranium that restricts it from being artificially created? Or, a reason why Tony wouldn't be interested in pursuing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found zero instances of Tony Stark attempting to produce synthetic Vibranium.  It seems as though it could be because the few attempts to produce synthetic Vibranium have been largely unsuccessful.  Roxxon attempted to produce synthetic Vibranium in *The Spider and the Ghost*.  The synthetic Vibranium Roxxon produces is unstable and rapidly decays under normal circumstances.  This makes it nearly useless as synthetic Vibranium.  It is possible that Tony Stark realized that any efforts to recreate Vibranium would be unsuccessful, but it wouldn't necessarily mean that he would never attempt it.